# How to enable button onclicklistener in android

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have two buttons, one is used for disabling a button's `onClickListener` function, and the other one is used to enable the `OnClickListener`. I successfully implemented the disable function, but how to enable back the onclick function when I click on the enable button?

```
public class Tab3 extends Fragment {
Button disable,enable;
TextView textView3;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View h = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)h.findViewById(R.id.RLtab3);
    textView3 = (TextView) h.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    disable = (Button) h.findViewById(R.id.disable);
    enable = (Button) h.findViewById(R.id.enable);
    disable.setOnClickListener(null);
    final Button btnAddARoom = new Button(getActivity());
    btnAddARoom.setText("Test");
    rl.addView(btnAddARoom);
    btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView3.setText("qweqweqweqwe");
            btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(null);
        }
    });

    disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(null);

        }
    });
    enable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView3.setText("qweqweqweqwe");
            btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    });


    return h;
}
```

Comment: instead of btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(null); use btnAddRoom.setEnable(true); and btnAddRoom.setDisable(true);

Comment: thanks , if i set btnAddRoom.setEnable(true) like this i cant implement if i get the ontouchlistener

Comment: is it possible i only disable on the onclicklistener function not the whole button?

Comment: No thats not possible

Comment: @Tang, check my answer man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setEnabled()` is the best option. But this will change the UI also. If you want to stick to the UI, use as follows.
Declare the `OnClickListener` outside and code like this:

```
View.OnClickListener myButtonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(myButtonClick); // Change here

disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(null);

    }
});
enable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        textView3.setText("qweqweqweqwe");
        btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(myButtonClick); // Change here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use predefined `setEnabled` method:

```
btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        textView3.setText("qweqweqweqwe");
        btnAddARoom.setEnabled(false);   //here
    }
});

disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        btnAddARoom.setEnabled(false);  //here

    }
});
enable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        textView3.setText("qweqweqweqwe");
        btnAddARoom.setEnabled(true);  //here
    }
});
```

Comment: It is 'setEnabled' not 'setEnable'.

Answer (score 0):

Use setEnable  method pass parameter like this

```
disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        btnAddARoom.setEnabled(false);//disable the button

    }
});
enable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        textView3.setText("qweqweqweqwe");
        btnAddARoom.setEnabled(true); //enable the button
    }
```

Comment: It is 'setEnabled' not 'setEnable'.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
    {

        Button a;
        Button b;


        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v)
        {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.a:
                    a.setOnClickListener(null);
                    b.setOnClickListener(this);
                    break;
                case R.id.b:
                    b.setOnClickListener(null);
                    a.setOnClickListener(this);

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

From the above answers you can use `setEnabled(true)` instead of  function `btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(null);`

If your continuing with your code please follow
A better design might be to do a check of the status in the `OnClickListener` and then determine whether or not the click should do something vs adding and clearing click listeners.